# Cannot Retrieve Location's longitude an latitude

Tags: android, permissions, gps, runtime, locationmanager

When I try to run my code, I always get this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

I can manually configure the coordinates in my emulator, but still, got the same error.

Here are my codes for getting Location Coordinates.

**LocationTracker.java**

```
    public class LocationTracker extends MainActivity implements LocationListener {
    MainActivity activity;
    Context context;
    Location location;
    LocationManager lm;

    double lat,longi;


    boolean isGpsEnabled = false;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    boolean canGetNetworkLocation = false;

    public LocationTracker (Context context) {
        this.context=context;
        getGPSLocation();
    }


    public Location getGPSLocation() {

        lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        isGpsEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);


       if (isGpsEnabled) {

           /** Check for RUNTIME PERMISSION */
           if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

               if (location == null) {      //Request for NEW DATA coming from GPS
                   lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,this);

                   if (lm != null) {    //Retrieve data from the earlier
                       location=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                       if (location != null) {
                            lat= location.getLatitude();
                            longi= location.getLongitude();
                       }
                   }
               }



           }else {
               ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},123);
           }

       }else {

       }

    return location;
       }

    /** GET LATITUDE METHOD */
        public double getLatitude() {
            if (location != null) {
                lat=location.getLatitude();
            }

            return lat;
        }

    /** GET LONGITUDE METHOD */
        public double getLongitude () {
            if (location != null) {
                longi=location.getLongitude();
            }
            return longi;
        }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        lat= location.getLatitude();
        longi=location.getLongitude();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

and **MainActivity class** for displaying Coordinates.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Context context;
DBHelper helper;
LocationTracker tracker;



TextView contactsTv,sendEmergencyTv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    helper=new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());


    /**
     * OnClick Listener in android
      */
    contactsTv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_createContacts);
    contactsTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, ContactsActivity.class); //redirect to the COntacts dsadsadsa

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

sendEmergencyTv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_sendEmergency);
    sendEmergencyTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tracker= new LocationTracker(MainActivity.this);
            double lat,longi;

            lat= tracker.getLatitude();
            longi= tracker.getLongitude();

            Toast.makeText(context,"Latitude: "+lat+ "Longitude: "+longi,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

}
```

By the way, I am not sure of placing a MainActivity instance inside the LocationTracker class in the requestPermission parameter.

Comment: Could you show the Logcat.

Comment: i already updated my post sir. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
           new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                       Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},123);
```

line causing issue because `activity` is `null`.

Use `((Activity)context)` instead of `activity`.like:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(((Activity)context),
           new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                       Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},123);
```

**NOTE:**

Also, because `LocationTracker` is a normal java class so no need to extends `Activity` in it.

Comment: i change the 'activity' param to 'context' but gives me an error, it says the method needs activity not context.

Comment: Can i ask what part of my code should I put the '((Activity)context) instead of activity' ?

Comment: @PhilipJ: `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(((Activity)context),
           new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                       Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},123);` line

Comment: it gives me the same error displayed in the logcat.

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},123);
```

`activity` is null since it was never assigned a value.

Change the `LocationTracker` constructor to take in `Activity` instead of `Context` as a parameter.

```
private Activity activity;

public LocationTracker (Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
    getGPSLocation();
}
```

NB: Make sure you implement `onRequestPermissionsResult` in that activity to know whether you've been granted the permissions or not.

Comment: Thanks for the response sir, but i changed the 'activity' param to 'context' and gives me same error i responded below.